# Devexpress Checkbox is not functioning

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

My intention is the msform is set visible = false at first, and then when i clicked on the checkbox and then the msform will appear but the problem is when i clicked on the checkbox the msform wont appear.The code is stated below:

ASP.net

```
<dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="popup" ClientInstanceName="popup" HeaderText="Detail" AllowDragging="true" ShowOnPageLoad="false" PopupHorizontalAlign="WindowCenter" PopupVerticalAlign="WindowCenter" runat="server" Width="60%" Height="60%">

  <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="mschkbox" runat="server" Text="Minesweeper?" Width="330px" OnCheckedChanged="mschkbox_CheckedChanged1" ClientIDMode="Static"></dx:ASPxCheckBox>


                  <dx:ASPxFormLayout ID="MsForm" Visible="False" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static">
                    <Items>

                    <dx:LayoutItem Caption="MS Product">
                        <LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
                            <dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
                                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="msproductbox" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="maxWidth"> 
                                    <ValidationSettings Display="Dynamic" RequiredField-IsRequired="true" ErrorDisplayMode="Text" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorTextPosition="Bottom" ErrorFrameStyle-Wrap="true"/>
                                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                            </dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
                        </LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
                    </dx:LayoutItem>

                   <dx:LayoutItem Caption="MS 1st Pilot Lot ID">
                        <LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
                            <dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
                                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="mslotidbox" runat="server"  Width="100%" CssClass="maxWidth"> 
                                    <ValidationSettings Display="Dynamic" RequiredField-IsRequired="true" ErrorDisplayMode="Text" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorTextPosition="Bottom" ErrorFrameStyle-Wrap="true"/>
                                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                            </dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
                        </LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
                    </dx:LayoutItem>
</dx:ASPxFormLayout>

</dx:ASPxPopupControl>
```

vb.net

```
Protected Sub mschkbox_CheckedChanged1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        If (mschkbox.Checked = True) Then
            MsForm.Visible = True
        Else
            MsForm.Visible = False
        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to set `AutoPostBack` attribute to `True` in order to handle `OnCheckedChanged` event properly in code-behind:

```
<dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="mschkbox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Text="Minesweeper?" 
Width="330px" OnCheckedChanged="mschkbox_CheckedChanged1" ClientIDMode="Static">
</dx:ASPxCheckBox>
```

If your `ASPxCheckBox` placed inside `ASPxGridView`'s `DataItemTemplate`, I suggest you to read [this issue](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q408144/aspxcheckbox-inside-aspxgridview-the-checkedchanged-event-is-not-raised-when-the-grid-is) and [this](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T572267/aspxgridview-the-checkedchanged-event-does-not-fire-when-aspxcheckbox-is-placed-inside), because you're using `ClientIDMode="Static"` attribute.

Related issue:

[ASPxCheckBox - The server-side CheckedChanged event doesn't fire in Navbar](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T492159/aspxcheckbox-the-server-side-checkedchanged-event-doesn-t-fire-in-navbar)